# Editing EmailField and FileField in Django using CSS

Tags: python, django, django-templates

How can I modify the height and width of EmailField, FileField and TextInputs in Django using CSS?

Answer (score 1):

You gave us not much information how you are about to use these fields. But I advise you to do nothing with Django forms. If it is possible, wrap them with `html` tags and set classes to them.

```
<div class="email">{{ my_form.email }}</div>

<style>.email input {width: 100px;}</style>
```

If you can't, you have to

1.[Override widgets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs)

2.Set attributes in form's constructor

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['email'].widget.attrs['style'] = 'width: 100px;'
```

Comment: It works for EmailField. But for FileField, it doesn't.. I tried <style>.file input { width: 400px; } </style>

Comment: It is another question how browsers apply style for elements. Try `<style>.file input { border: 1px red; }</style>`